# On a button click opening the image galary and sending to server

Tags: android

on a button click opening the image galary after selecting image within onActivityResult i am calling Asynctask(which is non activity) after executing all line within onActivityResult onCreate called again which should not happen my activity is portrait. i am facing this issue only in few device not all.

i am just putting the code wit

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        try {
            byte[] encode64 = null;

            encode64 = getGalleryDetails(picturePath);
            long fileSize = 0;
            fileSize = encode64.length;
            long filesizeKB = 0;
            filesizeKB = fileSize / 1024;
            System.out.println("file Size(KB) === " + filesizeKB);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "File size(KB): " + String.valueOf(filesizeKB),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (filesizeKB != 0 && filesizeKB > 1500) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "file size exceeded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("file size exceeded");

                data = null;
```

//                  pdialog.dismiss();
                }

```
            else {

                CommonUtilities.commonExtension = "jpg";
                upload = new SendImageToServer().execute(encode64).get();

                System.out.println("izhar" + upload);
                if (upload == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "errrr", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (upload != null) {
                    int startResponse = upload.indexOf("<return>")
                            + "<callId>".length();
                    int endResponse = upload.indexOf("</return>");
                    String returnResponse = upload.substring(startResponse,
                            endResponse);
                    int startPos = returnResponse.indexOf("g");
                    startPos = startPos + 2;
                    int endpos = returnResponse.length();
                    serverMessage = returnResponse.substring(startPos,
                            endpos);
                    Log.e("success", serverMessage);

                    if (serverMessage
                            .equalsIgnoreCase("Uploaded SuccessFully")) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Uploaded SuccessFully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception"+e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear can you re-frame it again..

Comment: @Alam please paste code here

Comment: @Alam you code looks fine. Did you try comment all code inside `onActivityResult ` or else part where you uploading to server. Is there still onCreate function called ?

Comment: i tested these code in many device in which working fine but in samsung galaxy s4 i am facing this issue continue